# What is the correct way to set _selected_action of Django admin's intermediate page that does not involve request.POST.getlist?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I was just testing my intermediate admin page and realized that I hit [bug 15742](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15742). The following comment seems to suggest that my code is wrong:

> The problem here involves how the "queryset" is preserved from the
>   original action handler to the code that handles POST for the
>   intermediate page. In the referenced blog post this is done like so:
>
> ```
> if not form:
>     form = self.AddTagForm(initial={'_selected_action': request.POST.getlist(admin.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)})
> ```
>
> This code is not actually using the queryset parameter passed into the
>   action function but rather the list of selected action checkboxes in
>   the post data, which is only going to be the 100 checkboxes on the
>   individual page. The action code should be using the passed queryset
>   parameter, which does contain the full list of all items, rather than
>   this post data. However Django's doc at the moment shows [​exactly this
>   technique](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages) of using the POST data, and that should be fixed.

So, what is the right way that does not involve `request.POST.getlist`? Here is what my apply_regex looks like right now:

```
# apply_regex.py
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.admin.helpers import ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME
from django.db import transaction
import re

class RegexForm(forms.Form):
    _selected_action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)
    from_regex = forms.CharField(label='From', required=True)
    to_regex = forms.CharField(label='To', required=True)
    #flags = forms.CharField(label='Flags')

def apply_regex_global(admin, request, queryset, fieldname):
    _selected_action = request.POST.getlist(ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)
    form = None
    if 'apply' in request.POST:
        form = RegexForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            with transaction.commit_manually():
                try:
                    for o in queryset:
                        old_value = getattr(o, fieldname)
                        new_value = re.sub(form.data['from_regex'],
                                           form.data['to_regex'], old_value)
                        setattr(o, fieldname, new_value)
                        o.save()
                    transaction.commit()
                finally:
                    transaction.rollback()
            admin.message_user(request, "Successfully applied a regex.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())
    if not form:
        form = RegexForm(initial={'_selected_action': _selected_action})
    return render(request, "apply_regex.html", {
        'form': form,
        'title': 'Apply regex'}
    )

# from apply_regex import apply_regex_global
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('product', 'vendor', 'devicetype')
    search_fields = ['product', ]
    formfield_overrides = make_textarea_use_textinput

    actions = ['apply_regex']
    def apply_regex(self, request, queryset):
        return apply_regex_global(self, request, queryset, "product")

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved this before. See this [diff](https://github.com/burke-software/django-mass-edit/commit/3c0e7d63ffc7843c075abfa5d78cfd26f82523d3). Basically get the id's from the queryset instead of POST data.

`queryset.values_list('id', flat=True)`

Comment: Thanks. Here's the trick I applied: `_selected_action = map(str, queryset.values_list('product_id', flat=True))`.